# How SN Handle Content Versioning

Tags: sensenet

I'm trying to know where SN saves versioning mode in its database for a specific container such as a folder!

I found [Status] column in [Versions] table but I noticed that its value remains 1 even though  I changed the mode from major to none and vise-versa.

I also traced it through SQL Profiler and found the following stored proc. triggered: proc_Version_Update.

Please elaborate.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you need a db solution? Isn't the REST or c# api sufficient for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a db solution (which is not the recommended one, use the REST or C# api if you can), you may take a look at the built-in database views. They will save you a few joins :-).

Versioning mode on containers is a regular field, called *Inheritable versioning mode*. Please note that this value determines the versioning behavior of child elements in that container, not the container's own versioning mode. If you need a value set on individual content items (like documents), look for the *VersioningMode* property.

The value you are looking for is stored in the *FlatProperties* table, as any other simple property, but it is easier to query using the view below.

#### Finding the column

Please execute the following script to find the correct column in the FlatProperties table:

```
SELECT [Id], [Page], [Column]
FROM [dbo].[PropertyInfoView]
where Name = 'InheritableVersioningMode'
```

The last column will contain the column name you need (e.g. *int_3*). Please also take a note of the *Page* value: sometimes there are so many fields in the system that a version occupies *more than one row* in the FlatProperties table.

#### Finding the property value

Execute the second script with the container path you are looking for (please **change the last selected column** to the one you have found in your db):

```
SELECT [NodeId], [Name], [Path], [VersionId], [int_3]
FROM [dbo].[SysSearchWithFlatsView]
where Path = @yourPath
```

The last column value will be the enum value (a number) you are looking for, one of the following:

```
Inherited = 0
None = 1
MajorOnly = 2
MajorAndMinor = 3
```